# Are academic papers required to have specific sections

Tags: paper-submission

I've seen that academic papers tend to have the sections Abstract, Introduction, Material and Methods, Results, Acknowledgements, and Literature Cited.  My question is if I wanted to publish an academic paper would it need to have these specific sections or could I have a different set of sections from the ones mentioned depending on the contents of my paper?

Comment: This is discipline specific.

Comment: Added here: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4472/13240

Comment: In general, it is better to follow a 'common' or accepted structure.  This is because your community 'expects' a certain structure.  This in turn allows a reader to find the required info quickly.

Comment: Which one would you be skipping and why? Or do you want to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is somewhat field (and even more so journal) specific.  You should have an idea the normal structure.  But then if you decide to separate Results and Discussion or combine them is a bit up to you.  (Or for long papers to use more topical subheadings.)

I recommend to take a look at '

1. Several papers in the journals you submit to (think of it as a biologist observing birds in the wild).
2. The specific journal's directions to authors (usually in January edition).
3. On Research by Wilson
4. Technical Writing (NASA pub) by Katzoff

---

After that, use best judgment as to what will help the customer (the reader best).  In my experience, after doing so, editors will leave your structure as is.

Answer (score 5):

That depends on where you want to publish. Some journals are strict on requiring a specific structure, e.g. [IMRAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMRAD), or on the naming of sections, while others are more freeform. As a general rule, read any "Guide to authors"/"Author information" or just try to follow the structure used in recent papers published in the venue of interest.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at a few papers in a few journals in your field. Probably will be illuminating.